# Change in Application / Services / BroadcastReceivers objects creation order Android 7

Tags: android, service, android-7.0-nougat

I store a few variable in a singleton instance of the Application class of my app.
Those variables can be accessed from anywhere in the app (activities, services, ...)
Everything worked fine since Samsung started rolling out their Android 7 class

Now I see some Exception caused by the Application instance not existing during a Service or Broadcastreceiver creation.
I never experienced this with other Android 7  devices (Nexus 6P, Pixel, ...)

For some reason it looks like Services are created before or during the Application class creation. I couldn't find anything about this in Android documentation.

Did anyone else experienced this?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication instance;

public static PodcastAddictApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        ...
    }
}

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        MyApplication.getInstance().getDB(); => NPE
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "Now I see some Exception caused by the Application instance not existing during a Service or Broadcastreceiver creation" -- please provide a [mcve], with the full Java stack trace along with the `Application`, `Service`, and `BroadcastReceiver` code that is triggering that crash.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but here's a sample. As explained the problem is that something changed in Android 7 (at least in Samsung ROM) and the Application object isn't always created before services are...

Comment: Are you using multidex? If so, are you sure that your custom application is in the proper DEX file?

Comment: No I'm not using multidex